# Were the North Vietnamese close to collapse in 1972?

Tags: vietnam-war, vietnam, collapse

I have seen snippets (first in Jeremiah Denton's book "When Hell was in Session" ) of information from recent scholarship that the North Vietnamese may have been ready to give up in 1972.  I have scoured recent books on the Vietnam War and have not found any that address the question of this theory.  Does anyone know of any publication(s) that addresses this? Any studies, papers, or books that have recently explored the inner deliberations of the North Vietnamese.

Comment: Where did you see these 'snippets'?

Comment: Highly unlikely they were "near collapse". They did suffer lot of casualties in 1972, but so did the enemy (South Vietnam) and Americans were getting ready to withdraw completely from Vietnam.

Comment: I first noticed it in Jeremiah Denton's book "When Hell was in Session."  His description of the actions of his prison staff offer a clue.  With this information, other reports began to corroborate the idea.  Unfortunately, I did not document the other sources, but the question grew.

Comment: Give up and collapse are radically different things.

Comment: Any more so than in Westmoreland's frequent pronouncements to that effect?

Answer (score 4):

> **Question:**
> Were the North Vietnamese close to collapse in 1972?

**Answer:**
I would say No, that wasn't the case.  For most of 1972 US troops involved in the war were being significantly reduced.  America was turning over the execution of the war to South Vietnamese forces.  In April,  North Vietnamese had started a significant large scale, three pronged offensive against the South.  While not the decisive victory the North had hoped for, they did gain ground.  US actions in Vietnam in 1972 were largely a response to this offensive.

What you are probable thinking of was the Nixon / Kissinger designed **[Operation Linebacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Linebacker)**.  The large scale American bombing campaign conducted May-Oct 1972 against the North.  The US targeted not only logistic infrastructure, but population centers in the North for the first time since 1967 **[Operation Rolling Thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Rolling_Thunder)**.   It was the first large scale use of smart weapons in the War.  Linebacker was designed not to collapse the North Vietnamese regime, nor win the war, rather blunt the ongoing North Vietnamese ground offensive into the South and also to force North Vietnamese concessions which had stalled peace talks since 1967.  Linebacker accomplished both of these goals.

The greatest opportunity for an American military "victory" in Vietnam was also a low water mark for US involvement.   The 1968 Tet offensive.  Prior to 1968, the United States had been slowly losing an asymmetric war in Vietnam.  In Jan of 1968 North Vietnam changed tactics and brought their clandestined forces in the south out of the shadows and directly challenged US forces across the south.  This lead to support for the war being reduced domestically within the United States,  it also lead to the devastation of North Vietnamese forces in the South.   It has been hypothesized that if the US had moved its forces to the frontiers and borders to prevent the North from re-infiltrating into the South, they could have won the war.  Perhaps not, but it was one of the greatest opportunities for victory in the war.   In reality the US never realized how tenuous the North's southern forces were after Tet.

Comment: What "smart weapons" do you have in mind?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The [LGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-guided_bomb) was developed during this time frame.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: [WP: Operation Linebacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Linebacker) -- "Between the 6th and the 15th, U.S. aircraft also struck and destroyed the Paul Doumer and Thanh Hóa bridges and the Yên Viên railway marshalling yard. This marked the introduction of laser-guided bombs against strategic targets in North Vietnam."

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo,  I've heard stories that laser guided bombs were so accurate the North Vietnamese soldiers took shelter from the bombing campaign in the courtyard of the Hanoi Hilton because it was one of the safest places in the city.   The US could target different buildings in the city  while safely not targeting the POW buildings.   That was a new concept in 1967.    During WWII and Korea huge strategic bombing campaigns involving hundreds of aircraft were used to destroy factories.   With smart bombs fewer and smaller aircraft could more reliable engage such targets.

Comment: @JMS I have also heard stories that laser-guided bombs were not all that accurate in the Gulf War. I do not see how bombs become less accurate over time. Perhaps the expectations had become too high by 1991.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  I haven't heard those stories but I do know that during the Gulf war especially the second most bombs dropped by the US were smart munitions.  Rather than smart bombs designed as such like in Vietnam when only like 2-4% of bombs were smart munitions.  During the gulf war kits were used to convert dumb bombs to smart weapons.   And unlike in Vietnam where relatively small fighters or tactical bombers were used  during the Gulf wars such munitions were dropped from large strategic bombers like the B-52 which can carry 20-30-40 times as many bombs per sorti.

Comment: @JMS What is the difference between "smart bomb" and "smart munition"? If one takes a dumb bomb and attaches a GPS/INS system to it, plus fins, I would call it a smart bomb. The problem with laser guidance is clouds and smoke. Tanks do use smoke screens for camouflage, for example. Some smoke is opaque in the infrared, too. And wasn't the whole problem in Vietnam the fact that it bordered China? The Pentagon remembered well what happened in Korea in late 1950.

Comment: Linebacker was B52s w fighter bomber escorts.  I believe the early Maverick and laser bombs were mostly F105s while B52s would have deployed mostly dumb bombs.  I could be wrong, easily, but I find it hard to believe B52s were dropping masses of smart bombs in 72.  Unless it's a fire and forget bomb, which is something different than just  smart bomb, you have to have someone track and aim it in and that's hard to do with multiple bombs.

Comment: See https://www.airuniversity.af.edu/Portals/10/AUPress/Papers/FP_0007_HEAD_WAR_FROM_ABOVE_CLOUDS.PDF  * In support, Seventh Air Force and Navy
fighters, using “smart bombs,” were to strike targets in populated areas to avoid civilian casualties. The B-52s would hit
targets within 10 miles of Hanoi.*

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica,   Yes the B-52 iis traditionally a carpet bombing WWII type strategic bomber.   My point was during the second gulf war the B-52's dropped mostly smart munitions.   Where each bomb could be individually aimed at a target with a high degree of accuracy.   Still so many bombs falling from an individual plain was a new thing as previously only smaller tactical bombers used smart munitions.

Comment: @JMS but this is question about 72, not Gulf War 1.  plus, if you search for smart bombs and b52, a good deal of the hits seem to be talking about recent upgrades to B52s.  there's something called a JDAM GPS bomb kit that predated that and that was used in Gulf War 2.  The other poster mentioning GPS:  there was no such thing in 72.  This whole talk about smart bombs, B52s and Linebacker looks pretty unfounded to me though smart bombs were first used against high value targets like bridges in Nam.  Just probably not in strategic bombing.  The rest is a good answer though.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica,  yes but I was responding to Rodrigo who was not speaking of 72 but the gulf war smart munitions.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica   Linebacker was the first use of smart bombs.  Not from Strategic Bombers like the B-52 but from tactical bombers and fighters.   B-52's were used in Linebacker but not with smart munitions.   Prior to the second gulf war 95% of munitions used by the USAF were conventional bombs.  that stat was switched in the second gulf war.